# Cracks on the side of fairly new tire

Tags: tire, crack

Today I noticed that the sides of my rear tire has these cracks

[image]

The tires have been installed last June, and since then have always been used at the proper pressure (initially at the low end of suggested range, in the last 3 months in the upper end). The bike is stored in a shed or, when I go to work, in an underground garage.

Is it normal to have these cracks? I have always seen them on rather old tires.

Comment: When the tires were installed, did you get the sense they were new then? (Picture is not very clear but it does not look 'new tire' to me.)

Comment: @Willeke, now it's no longer any more, after six months usage. When I installed it I think it was.

Comment: In that case I agree with @Batman that is might have been poorly storaged tires, (as most tires I used stayed new looking for a much longer time, the ones that did not were on a bike that had been in a shop for a long time.)

Comment: It looks to me like your brake pads are rubbing the tire.  Or is there some other reason for the mark just above the rim?

Comment: By the way, what pressure have you been running?

Comment: @DanielRHicks, in the range recommended on the tires. I don't remember it by hearth, probably 40-50 psi

Comment: I don't know the tire size, or your weight, but I'm guessing that 50 is too low for those tires.

Comment: @DanielRHicks, I checked this morning: the recommended range is 60-75 psi, and that's what I used

Comment: @DanielRHicks, the silver part above the rim is the reflective band. The dirty on it shows I don't really wash the tires...

Comment: The reflective band may be the answer.  In applying the band they may have overheated the tire, or applied some bad solvent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They may have been stored improperly (e.g. near a heater/source of ozone) or been old when you bought them. Also, if you wash your bike, you might be washing away some of the protectants in the tire from the manufacturer. That being said, this wear does happen relatively quickly depending on the conditions.

In any case, [tire cracks are not a big deal](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/tires.html#replacement) -- they don't affect the structural quality of a bicycle tire significantly. Replace the tire when you get punctures (which will likely happen before the cracks in the sidewalls and stuff become a problem) or you have structural damage (e.g. bulges in the sidewall). You can use [armor all](http://www.velonews.com/2014/04/bikes-and-tech/technical-faq/technical-faq-taking-care-of-unused-tires_325651) or something to help prevent cracks though.